# Node.js connecting to Oracle via only oracledb on production server

Tags: node.js, oracle, connection

Works great on dev machine.
Copy application to server and it doesn't connect.
i am using built in oracledb functionality so don't need the Oracle ODAC with it's TNSnames.ora file. (in fact i locally renamed ODAC folder and node app works great still).
On server i can telnet to hostname 1521 and it does connect, so i thought that proves is not a firewall issue. Any other ideas?

```js
async function DBQueryJDE(sqlquery)  {
  try {
    if (debugMode) {
      console.log('Oracle SQL:\n' + sqlquery);
    }
    var oracledb = require('oracledb');
    var connectionProperties = {
      user: process.env.DBAAS_USER_NAME || "....",
      password: process.env.DBAAS_USER_PASSWORD || "....",
      connectString: "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ....)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME= .....bherp.local)))"};

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
      oracledb.getConnection(connectionProperties, function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Oracle Connect Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
          return reject(err);
        } else {
```

**gives error on server:** `Oracle Connect Error: {"errorNum":0,"offset":0}`

see above.  should not have displayed error msg

Comment: I notice you hardcoded the service name in the connect string, is it the same on your server as your local dev machine?

Comment: dev machine is pointing to production service, so is the same.  (it's a read only copy of production)

Comment: Well this is interesting.    Even though i am not using thick mode, apparently oracledb checks the architecture of what is installed.  turned debug level up to find issue...

set DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL=64

node app

...
ODPI [09540] 2023-09-28 14:25:44.618: load by OS failure: D:\Oracle12c-ODAC\product\12.1.0\client_1\oci.dll is not the correct architecture
Oracle Connect Error: {"errorNum":0,"offset":0}

Comment: If you see those debug messages then you are definitely using Thick mode of node-oracledb 6, or are using an older version of node-oracledb.  The Thin mode of node-oracledb 6 doesn't load ODPI-C.